# Are there any drawbacks if you use setLayout(null) for say JFrame and use setBounds method to set the positions of components in that JFrame

Tags: java

Are there any drawbacks if you use setLayout(null) for say JFrame and use setBounds method to set the positions of components in that JFrame. GUI prospect.

Comment: Anyone else remember Borland's `XYLayout`?  Or why it was necessary?  (It took a `Rectangle` as a constraint and would always place the component at that exact location.  Maybe it was because a `null` layout was not allowed by AWT at the time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: if you want the components in that JFrame to automatically reposition and resize themselves when the user resizes the JFrame, you'll be disappointed! Otherwise, a null layout is fine.

Comment: How can I counter that. Is there any specific layout I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Laying Out Components in a Container](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). Download the examples and play with them to learn how to use layout managers. And remember that you can nest different layout managers to get your desired effect.

The only time I have ever had a reason to use a null layout is when you application has the ability to drag components around a panel. In this case you want to control the position through the dragging.

Otherwise you time is better spent learning the learning mangagers instead of worrying about the consequences of using a null layout.